# Merging nested lists whilst maintaining sub-sublists names

Tags: r, list

I am trying to combine lists by name whilst also maintaining the names of the lists *within* the nested lists.

The data structure looks like this:

```
Main list
 - sublist: "tree"
   - named num: "apple":   1  2  3
   - named num: "cherry":  4  5  6
 - sublist: "tree"
   - named num: "peach":   7  8  9
   - named num: "pear":   10 11 12
 - sublist: "house"
   - named num: "door":   20 21 22
   - named num: "window": 23 24 25
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Main list
 - sublist: "tree"
   - named num: "apple":   1  2  3
   - named num: "cherry":  4  5  6
   - named num: "peach":   7  8  9
   - named num: "pear":   10 11 12
 - sublist: "house"
   - named num: "door":   20 21 22
   - named num: "window": 23 24 25
```

(Side info: The actual data is multiple `csv` files. Each sublist represents a `csv` file and the sub-sublists `"apple"`, `"cherry"`, etc. are the names of the columns/variables inside the `csv` file.)

I tried the code below and the sublists get merged successfully. However it gets rid of the names like `"apple"`, `"cherry"`, `"pear"`. Their structure/format is no longer `named num` but just `num`. Can somebody help?

Code:

```
nm <- names(MainList)
MainList1 <- lapply(unique(nm), function(n) unname(unlist(MainList[nm %in% n])))
names(MainList1) <- unique(nm)
```

Edit: I added the original data.
This is what the data looks like originally. The main list is called `zF_10_agg1`, the sublists are called `306`, `371`, `371` and `389`. The `307` have different columns inside of them. I want the `VA01` and `VA02` columns of the two `371` lists inside ONE `371` list. I will have a more data later and thus more 371-like columns, but I use this smaller data set for now to make it work later more easily.

```
>      zF_10_agg1
    $`306`
        VA01_F0finEnv_sma      VA01_F0final_sma  VA01_jitterLocal_sma VA01_shimmerLocal_sma      VA01_mfcc_sma.0.      VA01_mfcc_sma.1.      VA01_mfcc_sma.2. 
             -0.190604977          -0.153007721           0.108863052           0.148992969           0.082147057           0.038587473           0.273740917 
         VA01_mfcc_sma.3.      VA01_mfcc_sma.4.      VA01_mfcc_sma.5.      VA01_mfcc_sma.6.      VA01_mfcc_sma.7.      VA01_mfcc_sma.8.      VA01_mfcc_sma.9. 
              0.247582486           0.048753122           0.120012640          -0.094071270           0.187793327           0.103478133           0.311836830 
        VA01_mfcc_sma.10.     VA01_mfcc_sma.11.     VA01_mfcc_sma.12.     VA01_mfcc_sma.13.     VA01_mfcc_sma.14.  VA01_F0finEnv_sma SD   VA01_F0final_sma SD 
              0.096803725          -0.009998885           0.289684409           0.299622366           0.218961033           1.039143987           1.098620495 
     VA01_F0finEnv_sma RG   VA01_F0final_sma RG 
              5.400888104           5.351059703 
    
    $`371`
        VA01_F0finEnv_sma      VA01_F0final_sma  VA01_jitterLocal_sma VA01_shimmerLocal_sma      VA01_mfcc_sma.0.      VA01_mfcc_sma.1.      VA01_mfcc_sma.2. 
               0.21414952            0.17037270           -0.11340110           -0.16155100           -0.09228902           -0.04335152           -0.30753726 
         VA01_mfcc_sma.3.      VA01_mfcc_sma.4.      VA01_mfcc_sma.5.      VA01_mfcc_sma.6.      VA01_mfcc_sma.7.      VA01_mfcc_sma.8.      VA01_mfcc_sma.9. 
              -0.27814928           -0.05477223           -0.13482953            0.10568541           -0.21097849           -0.11625365           -0.35033654 
        VA01_mfcc_sma.10.     VA01_mfcc_sma.11.     VA01_mfcc_sma.12.     VA01_mfcc_sma.13.     VA01_mfcc_sma.14.     VA01_F0finEnv_sma      VA01_F0final_sma 
              -0.10875522            0.01123336           -0.32544916           -0.33661406           -0.24599420            0.90763360            0.84537119 
        VA01_F0finEnv_sma      VA01_F0final_sma 
               5.58352735            5.10071294 
    
    $`371`
        VA02_F0finEnv_sma      VA02_F0final_sma  VA02_jitterLocal_sma VA02_shimmerLocal_sma      VA02_mfcc_sma.0.      VA02_mfcc_sma.1.      VA02_mfcc_sma.2. 
             1.851272e-16         -5.009943e-17         -2.348591e-17         -2.604552e-17         -2.391990e-17         -3.890029e-17         -2.785709e-17 
         VA02_mfcc_sma.3.      VA02_mfcc_sma.4.      VA02_mfcc_sma.5.      VA02_mfcc_sma.6.      VA02_mfcc_sma.7.      VA02_mfcc_sma.8.      VA02_mfcc_sma.9. 
             2.683726e-17         -2.083230e-17          5.737901e-18         -2.277669e-17          3.112273e-17         -2.453523e-18         -5.662469e-17 
        VA02_mfcc_sma.10.     VA02_mfcc_sma.11.     VA02_mfcc_sma.12.     VA02_mfcc_sma.13.     VA02_mfcc_sma.14.     VA02_F0finEnv_sma      VA02_F0final_sma 
             2.266112e-17          1.361854e-18          1.131963e-17         -4.091183e-17          8.561561e-18          1.000000e+00          1.000000e+00 
        VA02_F0finEnv_sma      VA02_F0final_sma 
             1.124750e+01          1.369369e+01 
    
    $`389`
        VA03_F0finEnv_sma      VA03_F0final_sma  VA03_jitterLocal_sma VA03_shimmerLocal_sma      VA03_mfcc_sma.0.      VA03_mfcc_sma.1.      VA03_mfcc_sma.2. 
             1.586292e-18         -9.464618e-17         -2.369378e-17          2.853813e-17         -9.629405e-17         -5.495508e-17         -2.202477e-17 
         VA03_mfcc_sma.3.      VA03_mfcc_sma.4.      VA03_mfcc_sma.5.      VA03_mfcc_sma.6.      VA03_mfcc_sma.7.      VA03_mfcc_sma.8.      VA03_mfcc_sma.9. 
            -4.454892e-17         -7.952470e-17         -1.056807e-17         -6.211858e-17          4.154178e-18         -8.151347e-18          1.995314e-18 
        VA03_mfcc_sma.10.     VA03_mfcc_sma.11.     VA03_mfcc_sma.12.     VA03_mfcc_sma.13.     VA03_mfcc_sma.14.     VA03_F0finEnv_sma      VA03_F0final_sma 
             3.121848e-17          2.181543e-17          8.159633e-17          6.164483e-19          2.416510e-17          1.000000e+00          1.000000e+00 
        VA03_F0finEnv_sma      VA03_F0final_sma 
             3.918357e+00          7.132235e+00
```

**Data :**

```
    list(`306` = c(VA01_F0finEnv_sma = -0.190604977349467, VA01_F0final_sma = -0.15300772088343, 
    VA01_jitterLocal_sma = 0.108863051649501, VA01_shimmerLocal_sma = 0.14899296872475, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.0. = 0.0821470570401912, VA01_mfcc_sma.1. = 0.0385874726552808, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.2. = 0.273740917400523, VA01_mfcc_sma.3. = 0.247582485577918, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.4. = 0.048753122175165, VA01_mfcc_sma.5. = 0.120012639707355, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.6. = -0.0940712695127309, VA01_mfcc_sma.7. = 0.187793326639453, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.8. = 0.103478133127875, VA01_mfcc_sma.9. = 0.311836829876786, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.10. = 0.096803725447679, VA01_mfcc_sma.11. = -0.00999888512522001, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.12. = 0.289684409002433, VA01_mfcc_sma.13. = 0.299622366044721, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.14. = 0.218961033004239, `VA01_F0finEnv_sma SD` = 1.03914398679305, 
    `VA01_F0final_sma SD` = 1.09862049506063, `VA01_F0finEnv_sma RG` = 5.40088810381152, 
    `VA01_F0final_sma RG` = 5.35105970310478), `371` = c(VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 0.214149520006098, 
    VA01_F0final_sma = 0.170372695167837, VA01_jitterLocal_sma = -0.113401101476438, 
    VA01_shimmerLocal_sma = -0.161550995230132, VA01_mfcc_sma.0. = -0.0922890207323388, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.1. = -0.0433515233801915, VA01_mfcc_sma.2. = -0.307537264407489, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.3. = -0.278149284560315, VA01_mfcc_sma.4. = -0.0547722348834566, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.5. = -0.134829528812893, VA01_mfcc_sma.6. = 0.105685409254896, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.7. = -0.210978491988385, VA01_mfcc_sma.8. = -0.116253654332496, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.9. = -0.350336539062199, VA01_mfcc_sma.10. = -0.108755217127712, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.11. = 0.0112333581977285, VA01_mfcc_sma.12. = -0.325449156567845, 
    VA01_mfcc_sma.13. = -0.336614064436232, VA01_mfcc_sma.14. = -0.245994196780729, 
    VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 0.907633595217961, VA01_F0final_sma = 0.845371190998525, 
    VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 5.58352735270808, VA01_F0final_sma = 5.10071293943663
    ), `371` = c(VA02_F0finEnv_sma = 1.85127192814681e-16, VA02_F0final_sma = -5.00994289546507e-17, 
    VA02_jitterLocal_sma = -2.34859079707077e-17, VA02_shimmerLocal_sma = -2.60455164544764e-17, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.0. = -2.39198962485355e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.1. = -3.89002856985193e-17, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.2. = -2.78570899311261e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.3. = 2.68372615000544e-17, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.4. = -2.08322992987213e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.5. = 5.73790146364059e-18, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.6. = -2.27766888801672e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.7. = 3.11227273727354e-17, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.8. = -2.45352291763184e-18, VA02_mfcc_sma.9. = -5.66246851843269e-17, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.10. = 2.26611187363704e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.11. = 1.36185358636217e-18, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.12. = 1.13196270572855e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.13. = -4.09118309040634e-17, 
    VA02_mfcc_sma.14. = 8.56156119316215e-18, VA02_F0finEnv_sma = 1, 
    VA02_F0final_sma = 1, VA02_F0finEnv_sma = 11.2475000713838, VA02_F0final_sma = 13.6936948927086
    ), `389` = c(VA03_F0finEnv_sma = 1.58629187875084e-18, VA03_F0final_sma = -9.46461808448016e-17, 
    VA03_jitterLocal_sma = -2.36937840621222e-17, VA03_shimmerLocal_sma = 2.85381254827705e-17, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.0. = -9.6294053113996e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.1. = -5.49550802238737e-17, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.2. = -2.20247732336464e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.3. = -4.454892003863e-17, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.4. = -7.9524696067784e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.5. = -1.05680749785702e-17, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.6. = -6.21185832013518e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.7. = 4.15417752575213e-18, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.8. = -8.15134676706638e-18, VA03_mfcc_sma.9. = 1.99531361473134e-18, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.10. = 3.1218480555731e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.11. = 2.1815428854396e-17, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.12. = 8.15963331541171e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.13. = 6.16448325097666e-19, 
    VA03_mfcc_sma.14. = 2.41651014444211e-17, VA03_F0finEnv_sma = 1, 
    VA03_F0final_sma = 1, VA03_F0finEnv_sma = 3.91835747651944, VA03_F0final_sma = 7.13223541696321
    ))
```

Comment: It may be easier to help if you share the actual data, not the structure tree. You may use `dput(MainList)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it did not work. I posted an update with the actual data, as well as a report on your attempt in the initial question and marked it by "Edit".

Comment: dput() is not a method for answering the question. It is actualy a method for reproducible sharing of the data. Posting your data as the output of dput() helps anyone trying to help with your actual data, rather than  Just the data structure

Comment: Thank you for your help on sharing data more easily. I will consider this next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use

```
zF_10_agg2 <- lapply(split(zF_10_agg1, names(zF_10_agg1)), 
     function(x) unlist(unname(x)))
```

-output

```
str(zF_10_agg2)
List of 3
 $ 306: Named num [1:23] -0.1906 -0.153 0.1089 0.149 0.0821 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:23] "VA01_F0finEnv_sma" "VA01_F0final_sma" "VA01_jitterLocal_sma" "VA01_shimmerLocal_sma" ...
 $ 371: Named num [1:46] 0.2141 0.1704 -0.1134 -0.1616 -0.0923 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:46] "VA01_F0finEnv_sma" "VA01_F0final_sma" "VA01_jitterLocal_sma" "VA01_shimmerLocal_sma" ...
 $ 389: Named num [1:23] 1.59e-18 -9.46e-17 -2.37e-17 2.85e-17 -9.63e-17 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:23] "VA03_F0finEnv_sma" "VA03_F0final_sma" "VA03_jitterLocal_sma" "VA03_shimmerLocal_sma" ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this does not work. I edited the main question so maybe this makes my question better to understand. 

This is my translated attempt of your submission: 

`zF_10_agg1 <- lapply(zF_10_agg, function(zF_10_agg) lapply(split(zF_10_agg, names(zF_10_agg)), function(x) do.call("c", x)))`
.
This is the error message: `Error in do.call("c", x) : second argument must be a list`

Comment: @bash-asker sorry, I was thinking that you had a nested list.  Can you try the updated solution